# Why registering a user with Facebook on Firebase does not register the email? - Android

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication, email

I followed all the steps of the documentation, for registration through Facebook
But when registering I get this:

[image]

The email comes out as (-) null

this is my code:

```
      private void initLoginWithFacebook(){
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken, AccessToken currentAccessToken) {

        }
    };


    loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager,  new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());



        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {

        }
    });


    accessTokenTracker.startTracking();

    mAccessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    if(mAccessToken != null){
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, NavActivity.class);
        intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent1);

    }


}


private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleFacebookAccessToken:" + token);


    AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
    auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());


                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                        TastyToast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                TastyToast.LENGTH_SHORT, TastyToast.ERROR).show();
                    }

                }
            });
}
```

So far I have not found a way to fix this and I do not know how to do it

Comment: just check your authentication settings in firebase console first

Comment: The settings are enabled @Piyush

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because Facebook allows users to sign-up only with their phone number and not with the email address. There are many users who don't complete their profile by adding their email address and this is the reason you are getting nothing there.

You'll be asking, ok but why am I not receiving the phone number instead of the email address? This is happening because of Facebook Policies. They don't make the user phone number public and as far as I read, they will not make it also in the future.

Comment: Thaks! it helps.